# Why does disposing a JDialog box twice in a row result in this kind of effect

Tags: java, performance, debugging, swing, dll

I solved a bug today after almost five weeks of effort.    What was happening was the CPU on the client machine was spiking (at 50 to 100 percent) after I disposed of a JDialog box twice in a row.

I actually disposed of it in the object and then in the method that created the object, a stupid bug.   It took me a while to find it because instead of causing a null pointer exception, I would see in process explorer lots of CSWITCH Deltas associated with MSVCR71.dll.

Using a profiler led me to the right solution.
My questions:

1. Why didn't I get a null pointer exception?
2. What was the connection between the high CPU and the CSWITCH Deltas?
3. Why would trying to dispose a dialog box twice cause this?

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heavyweight peer [`Window`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) that is the parent of the `JDialog` is managed by the host operating system.

1. There is no null pointer exception because that is in Java, not the host OS.
2. The connection lies in [`dispose()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29), which communicates with the host OS via JNI.
3. I suspect, but cannot prove, that the affected `.dll` is to blame.